# Python reading from txt file

Tags: python

I want to pull in a bunch of names from a text file into python (v3.6.5).

My text file is plain text (file.txt) and I have each name on one line

```
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3 etc.
```

In python, I have verified that the path works with the following code

```
path_to_file = "D:\(my user name)\Documents\names.txt"
file_object = open(path_to_file, "r")
print(file_object)
```

That returns the path to the file in the console which means it is working.

---

Now I want to put the names into a list.

So

```
names = fileobject.read()
print(names)
```

which returns

```
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3 etc.
```

But it is not like a normal list (ie.

```
["name 1", "name 2", "name 3"] etc
```

so if I ask it to call the second name

```
print(names[1])
```

it will print

```
a
```

as in the second letter of the first name (remember 0 is the start of the list)

How can I make it like a normal array where each name is in quotes separated by a comma with square brackets arround the outside.

Comment: `path_to_file = "D:\(my user name)\Documents\names.txt"` -- be careful with this, `\` has special meanings. Use `path_to_file = r"D:\(my user name)\Documents\names.txt"` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of answers with poor practices here. The best way is to realise that you can iterate on file objects directly

```
path_to_file = r"D:\(my user name)\Documents\names.txt"
with open(path_to_file) as file_object:  # this is a safe way of opening files
    for line in file_object:
        print(line)
```

Or if you want to save that as a list and access by index `names[0]` use:

```
with open(path_to_file) as file_object:  # this is a safe way of opening files
    names = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file_object]  # remove \n at end

print(names[0]) # --> name 1
print(names[1]) # --> name 2
```

---

A quick explanation about the `with`. Don't do

```
file = open(path)
# do stuff
```

because you risk corrupting your data. You must close your file. However

```
file = open(path)
# do stuff
file.close()
```

is also dangerous since `#do stuff` may fail, in which case the file will never be closed. One way is to use

```
try:
    file = open(path)
    # do stuff
finally:
    file.close()
```

where no matter what happens in `# do stuff`, the `file.close()` will always be executed. Still, this is a bit verbose, and a quicker way to write this for file objects is

```
with open(path) as file:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Yes thankyou. This works well.

Then I use `names = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(path-to-file)]`

Comment: @Hugo No no, that has the same issues as the `file = open(path)`. See my edit if you want to remove the `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Content of file is one string and not list of strings.

`read()` method returns the whole file as one string. if you want lines you have to split this string by "\n" which is newline in text files.

Or you can use `readlines()` method instead and you will get same results as with read and split.

Comment: or you can just iterate over the file object, which avoids filling your memory (and eventually crashing) for no good reason...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `with` statement. The `with` statement is used to wrap the execution of a block with methods defined by a context manager. This allows common `try , except , finally` usage patterns to be encapsulated for convenient reuse.

you can do like this.

```
>>> path_to_file = "D:\(my user name)\Documents\names.txt"
>>> with open(path_to_file ,'r') as f:
...     [file.replace('\n','') for file in f]
or
...     [file.rstrip('\n') for file in f]
```

Comment: Maybe use `strip()` instead of `replace()`?

Comment: that is also we can do and added that in my answer

Comment: @SimonBrahan or `rstrip` or even just `[:-1]`

Comment: yes you are correct ..instead using strip we can use [rstrip](http://ics.misterv.ca/6-0-python/python-notes/string-processing/-strip-lstrip-rstrip).. @FHTMitchell